# How to make a list containing a list of elements read from the user input?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I tried to input list as an element, but the expected result is not a list containing a list of elements. Does the code below need modification or is it incorrect?

For example, `[1,2,3]` `[3,4,5]`, but the result is not like `[[1,2,3] ,[3,4,5]]`

```
s = raw_input()
numbers = map(list , s.split())
print number
```

Answer (score 0):

Your objective is to store the input lists into a list (say 'l'). Iterate over input string, store the string letters between '[' and ']' into a temp list (say list1) which can be tracked using simple if-condition, and append the collected lists (list1 into the main list ('l'):

```
l = list()

s = input("input plz")

for a in s:
    if a =='[':
        list1 = list()
    elif a ==']':
        l.append(list1)
    elif a !=',' and a!=' ':
        list1.append(int(a))

print(l)
```

Comment: the result is showing error , can you please write how to formate input

Comment: if u use python 3.5, it won't show you the error. For 2.7 use raw_input instead input

Comment: **output of the code is**  : user input[1,2,3] [3,4,5]
                                            **['[1', '2', '3] [3', '4', '5]']** and this is not as expected.

Comment: Please explain what the code does instead of posting code-only answer.

Comment: **i write this code**      >>>    s = (raw_input())
>>>numbers = s.split()
>>>list1 = list(numbers)
>>>print list1       , but the output contains user inputed list as an string. there's any way to change .

Answer (score 0):

s.split itself return list
Try this

```
s = raw_input()
numbers = s.split()
print numbers
```

output

> ['2', '5', '6']

For multidimensional list

```
li=list()
s = raw_input()
while s!="Stop":
    li.append(s.split())
    s = raw_input()

print li
```

Output

> [['2', '3', '5', '4'], ['2', '5', '63', '6'], ['2', '3', '56', '2']]

Answer (score 0):

This can be a possible solution.

```
s1 = []
ask = raw_input("Yes/No: ")
while ask == "Yes":
    s2 = raw_input()
    lst_one = s2.split()
    s1.append(s2)
    print s1
    ask = raw_input("Yes/No: ")
```